# Prove that $u^p-v^p = (u-v)(u^{p-1}+u^{p-2}v+u^{p-3} v^2+...+uv^{p-2}+v^{p-1})$ by induction over p.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, induction, real-numbers

In the course of a book on Introduction the Real Analysis the author presents the formula $$u^p-v^p = (u-v)(u^{p-1}+u^{p-2}v+u^{p-3} v^2+...+uv^{p-2}+v^{p-1})$$ in order to prove a theorem, and leaves "as an exercise to the reader" to prove this formula by induction over p.

I tried it for 3 days, but can't seem to figure this one out (there are many other "exercises to the reader" in the course of the book). Could you please help me?

Comment: Hint: multiply both sides by $u$ and then add $(u-v)v^p$ to both sides.

Comment: Aside from that, what have you been trying these past 3 days? While many paths may look like dead ends, many aren't. If you show us what you've tried, we could more easily direct you from where you left off.

Comment: Solve *what*? You are trying to prove it by induction over $p$. And that's not an excuse for not showing your work. Please [edit] accordingly, as [problem statements](http://goo.gl/mLWc8) are usually not considered [good questions](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ).

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
  u^{p+1}-v^{p+1}  &= u^{p+1}-u^pv+u^pv-v^{p+1} \\
   &= u^p(u-v) +v (u^{p}-v^{p}) \\
   &=  u^p(u-v) + v (u-v)(u^{p-1}+u^{p-2}v+u^{p-3} v^2+\dots+uv^{p-2}+v^{p-1})\\
   &= (u-v)\Big[u^{p}+v(u^{p-1}+u^{p-2} v+\dots+uv^{p-2}+v^{p-1})\Big] \\
   &= (u-v)\Big[u^{p}+u^{p-1}v+u^{p-2} v^2+\dots+uv^{p-1}+v^{p}\Big]
\end{align}

Comment: I just wonder why is this down voted? And twice! And with no explanation or question! Obviously, you have problems with your own moral principles.